# Pandas giving error while adding a list to a Series

Tags: pandas

I am having error trying to add a list to a pandas series A. The series A has 2 elements:

```
1     0.0
46    0.0
Name: ACCT_BAL, dtype: float64
```

The list, which is created by calling tolist() on a Series (The Series is 1 column from a dataframe) has 1 element:

```
[0.0]
```

But when I do:

```
A=A.add(list)
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Lengths must be equal
```

Comment: If it's just one element do `A = A.add(lst[0])`.

Comment: Thank you. It can be many elements because the list is dynamically created from a field in a dataframe. What does it mean:Lengths must be equal?

Comment: Are you trying to extend your Series or sum up values in the list with the Series? `pd.Series.add` does the latter, which is why it wants the list to be the same length as the Series.

Comment: Basically, how do you "add" `[2,3,4]` and `[1,2]`? It's natural that you *can* add `[2,3,4]` and `[1,2,3]` which gives `[3,5,7]` because there's an alignment between elements (hence the equal length).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `pd.Series.append(..., ignore_index=True)` is what you're looking for:

```py
df=pd.Series([0.0, 0.0], index=[1,46], name="ACCT_BAL")
df_2=pd.Series([1.0, 20, 2.3], name="irrelevant_col_name")
df_3=pd.Series([765], name="irrelevant_col_name")

df=df.append(df_2, ignore_index=True)

#outputs:
>>> df
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     1.0
3    20.0
4     2.3
dtype: float64

df=df.append(df_3, ignore_index=True)

#outputs:
>>> df
0      0.0
1      0.0
2      1.0
3     20.0
4      2.3
5    765.0
dtype: float64
```